# How to make a template with an overloaded function based on the type?

Tags: c++

I came across a numeric_limits static method.
For example, numeric_limits::infinity(); gives the infinity when we do
numeric_limits::infinity(), we get a different result.

My understanding is that infinity() is a static method of the class numeric_limits.
If I want to implement similar kind of mechanism how can I do so. How to make a template class that will return a different answer based on
the type passed.

Comment: Can you extend your code example? There is no type passed?

Comment: [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) uses [*specialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of the template structure, not overloading.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a specialization for each type you want to supports, and give each specialization member functions with the same name that return different values, and even different types.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct my_limits;

template <>
struct my_limits<int> {
    static constexpr int max() {
        return 2000;
    }
};

template <>
struct my_limits<char> {
    static constexpr char max() {
        return 127;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << my_limits<int>::max() << ' ' << static_cast<int>(my_limits<char>::max());
}
```